# Android build application: gradlew does not exist

Tags: android, build

This is the first Android application I am running. I am reading up the tutorial and following it (as much as I can).

I would like to get myself comfortable with the CLI instead.

I created a project using "android" executable. Although to build the application it says to run the "gradlew" executable which is supposed to be in my project's root. I don't see it there.

What might I be missing ?

Created the project using

```
android create project --target 1 --name HelloWorld --path HelloWorld --activity HW --package com.developers.helloworld
```

Comment: So, like, you put your project at C:/HelloWorld?

Comment: ~/Programming/Android/apps/HelloWorld

Comment: Ok, then put this into the path section, not "HelloWorld" :P

Comment: Oh, I assumed that it would create it in the folder I was running the program from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, it does not exist, because when you create a project from the command line, the generated project is an Android project **without** gradle.

You have 3 options however:

- Use the official IDE supported by Google - [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) - to build and run your apps. **(recommended)**, or
- Download and install [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) and
  a) Change directory to your project root.
  b) Execute from command line `ant debug` to compile your project.
  c) Then `adb install YourApp.apk` to transfer the apk to your device (once compiled successfully, apk you'll find in the `bin` directory), or
- Manually add `Gradle` to your project. But keep in mind that Gradle is a build tool that expects a project to have a specific directory structure, if you don't want to configure anything.

In general, is good to know what happens behind a shiny IDE, and know let say, how to generate an android project on your own, from the command line. This also is useful when you want to use an IDE of your preference, or have more control over the Android build.

But, honestly, if you are just getting started with Android, I would highly suggest you use Android Studio. With this option you get an intelligent code editor, implicit support for Gradle, access to a multitude of open source projects from Github that already use the gradle project structure, and other advantages.

**UPDATE: how to view logs**:

- from command line: `adb logcat`
- from GUI: navigate to `<android-sdk>/tools`, find and open `monitor`.
  Once the window opens, you'll find a tab called `LogCat`, usually located in the left - bottom of the window, but if it is not there, then go to: `Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat -> OK`, to add it.

note: make sure only one device is connected to `adb bridge`

for filtering:  [image]

check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) & [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat).

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer is brilliant. Yes, I installed "ant" and was able to build and install my application. Yes, I do agree that Studio would be a smarter way to start. Although I prefer the command line more :)
Q: Is there a way I can run the application on the device and few a log for runtime errors ?

Comment: Wonderful thanks :) And is there a way, I can have my log filtered ? Its currently spitting out way too much activity. Can I have only my apps activity being filtered ? Or maybe just errors ?

Comment: @PrakashRaman [do check this for complete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28808210/1761003)

Comment: Thanks ! :) You answered my questions in two places :)

Answer (score 1):

The `tools/andoird create project` has the `--gradle` flag to specify to use the `gradle` template instead of `ant` template.

Use `tools/android  create project help` for more details.