# Android: The right way to debug an running application (runtime errors/log)

Tags: android, debugging, runtime

I am new to Android development. I have been going through the tutorials.

I would like to know which is the right way to debug / log an application during its execution. I am guessing I should be able to execute my application directly on my android device and be able to view a log or so to catch runtime errors and logs?

How could I accomplish this ?

I am using this to install the application on my phone

```
adb install <path to apk>
```

p.s. I am sure this question might seem like something I should already know. But I could not figure it out :) Hence I am here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build on the command line with ant. [See this guide](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html).

& install it by using `adb` on the command line.

```
adb install MyApp.apk
```

path of apk with file extension

---

## update

for getting `logcat` or crash report

do this way:

```
adb logcat
```

[image]

> note: make sure only one device is connected to `adb bridge`

for filtering:  [image]

check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) & [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat).

Comment: Sorry, I meant, I am using "adb" to install the application. Although it just installs it, it does not run it on the phone directly. Therefore, I have no way to log the application.

Comment: Ah, thats great ! Although, the log is spitting out way too much :) most of it is just the activity of my phone. Anyway, I can filter it down to only what my application is doing ?

Comment: @PrakashRaman I have added that information also, go through the links given.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted :)